# Unsmooth zooming images with Kinect - Correction needed in approach

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect

I am trying to get zoom in/out effect using Kinect. The basic idea is:

1. Detect if both hands are raised `bool lefthand, righthand;`
2. Calculate the distance between hands `prevDistance`
3. In the next frame captured, if the distance between hands is less than `prevDistance`, then ZoomOut else ZoomIn

This works for me but the approach doesn't lead to very smooth zooming in/out.

```
    bool lefthand=false, righthand=false;
    float prevDistance=0;

//Inside SkeletonFrameReady event

if(lefthand && righthand && prevDistance=0)
{
prevDistance = skeleton.Joints[JointID.HandRight].Postion.X - skeleton.Joints[JointID.HandLeft].Position.X;
}
if(lefthand && righthand)
{
ZoomingFunction(skeleton.Joints[JointID.HandRight].Postion.X, skeleton.Joints[JointID.HandLeft].Position.X, prevDistance);
}
if(!lefthand && !righthand)
{
prevDistance =0;
}
```

The zooming function:

```
private void ZoomingFunction(double RPostion, LPosition, double curDistance)
{
//0.3 has been added to get kind of integral points to zoom, else the zooming occurs very fast to control
    if(RPosition - LPosition < curDistance - 0.3F)
    {
//Zoom out
    img.Width -=20;
    }
    if(RPosition - LPosition > curDistance + 0.3F)
    {
//Zoom in
    img.Width +=20;
    }
}
```

The approach doesn't look very elegant to me. I was trying to get some smooth zooming effect, as in this Kinect demo of Worldwide Telescope. Link: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1-tMp4WkQjA

Any suggestions to improve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are 2 possible problems to approach here.

The **first one** is error accumulation. This happens when on each frame, you get from the SD the position for the hands + a little error (or noise). My solution for this would be:

1. When you detect that the user lifted the hands and you're ready to start zooming, store the distance between the hands and the zoom level at that moment (let's call them `startDistance and startZoom`)
2. Each frame, calculate a new zoom level based on the original value, original hand distance and new distance.
   You could do something like this:

```
float newWidth = startWidth * currentDistance / startDistance;
float newHeight = startHeight * currentDistance / startDistance;
```

This should minimize any error accumulation.

The **second problem** is to improve the smoothness of your zoom and remove any noise you might get from the SDK. This is pretty simple. You can try interpolating the hand distance values between current and previous frame. If needed you can try interpolating across more frames if you really get noisy values.

You can do something like this:

```
float interpolatedDistance = (currentDistance + prevDistance) / 2;
float newWidth = startWidth * interpolatedDistance / startDistance;
float newHeight = startHeight * InterpolatedDistance / startDistance;
prevDistance = currentDistance;
```

Where `currentDistance` is the distance between the hands at this frame and `prevDistance` is the distance between hands in the previous frame.

Tell us if this helped

Answer (score 0):

The only two things I may suggest is having a ScaleTransfrom on the UIElemnt your resizing and use binding. The only other thing is I believe it's. Choppy because your moving at too high of an delta. Have a few more if statements that capture different ranges with different deltas like 1, 4, and 6 maybe

#### EDIT

Your going to have to play around with the values but I would do something like this to start:

```
double deltaPosition = RPosition - LPosition;
if(deltaPosition  < curDistance - 0.3f)
    img.Width -= 4;

else if(deltaPosition  < curDistance - 0.2f)
    img.Width -= 2;

else if(deltaPosition  < curDistance - 0.1f)
    img.Width -= 1;

else if(deltaPosition  > curDistance + 0.3F)
    img.Width += 4;

else if(deltaPosition  > curDistance + 0.2F)
    img.Width += 2;

else if(deltaPosition  > curDistance + 0.1F)
    img.Width += 1;
```

Comment: In this context, can you give a bit more detail about what is meant by delta values?